How strongly would a Harris administration be committed to opposing "fracking?"
"Fracking" is a major issue for the swing state of Pennsylvania, which works in Trump's favor ("Drill, baby, drill.") Biden's stance on this matter could cost the Democrats, Pennsylvania, and with it, the 2024 election.
Has Harris successfully distanced herself from Biden on this matter? Or does she support Biden's position, even if it means "refusing to cut off an arm to save a life?" Or don't people see it that way?

The question feels kind of muddied. Biden's stance on fracking has little relevance to the Democrats' chances in the 2024 election because he's not their candidate; Harris is.

@F1Krazy: I have hopefully clarified the question.

"refusing to cut off an arm to save a life?" You mean it might be a significant issue for the election? Probably depends on how undecided voters see the matter. How do people in Pennsylvania see fracking?

Can you explain how being anti-fracking is 'refusing to cut off an arm to save a life'? I would rather see the pro fracking opinion that way. Yes, fracking provides some jobs in the US and helps to become independent of oil producers in the middle east. But it is also a technology to produce oil which produces huge amounts of CO2 and hence should be phased out in the medium term.

@quarague I think the metaphor is that "life == her campaign" and "arm == her anti-fracking position". So she needs to step back on fracking to save her campaign. But as pointed out in the answers, the premise of the metaphor is simply wrong.

Sorry, what exactly is Biden's stance on fracking? This question weasels around naming it but implies that he is opposed - yet the answers say the opposite. This seems a lot like asking whether she stopped beating her spouse.

@MisterMiyagi To be fair, the Trump campaign has certainly spent plenty of time talking up how anti-fracking Biden/Harris are supposed to be.

@quarague Think a bit through your analysis.  Will an anti-fracking position win a POTUS election at this time?  It will not.  And if such an anti-fracking platform loses, who gets to run policy for the next 4 years:  Beautiful-coal-Trump.  One really needs to tailor one's campaign on what the electorate will carry.  Emissions need to come down, drastically from US/Canadian levels and I do my best to adjust my lifestyle.  But I also recognize that over-ambitious position will be counterproductive.  Ditto Gaza protest crowd:  one side is likely to be drastically worse than the other.

@MisterMiyagi What matters in the election is what voters think their position is, much less than what it actually is. Since Biden has promoted lots of green policies (particularly in the Inflation Reduction Act), and fracking is not very green, they're left with an anti-fracking impression.

This very topic came up during the Trump-Harris debate (full text):

LINSEY DAVIS: Vice President Harris, in your last run for president you said you wanted to ban fracking...


VICE PRESIDENT KAMALA HARRIS: ... But in particular, let's talk about fracking because we're here in Pennsylvania. I made that very clear in 2020. I will not ban fracking. I have not banned fracking as Vice President of the United States. And, in fact, I was the tie-breaking vote on the Inflation Reduction Act, which opened new leases for fracking. My position is that we have got to invest in diverse sources of energy so we reduce our reliance on foreign oil.

From the subtext of the question, as it was asked, she might have been more anti-fracking than Biden in the past.
But she's also pretty clear that she's walked that back.  What voters will make of it, either way, is up for grabs.
p.s. About Biden's position and "refusing to cut off an arm":
Forbes 2021 - didn't ban it, good
Food and Water Watch, 2021 - didn't ban it, bad
Washington Monthly, 2023 - didn't ban it, good
Undoubtedly, undoubtedly, Trump is more fracking-friendly.  But let's be real, Biden hasn't exactly been an anti-fracking crusader.
